# Change value of JQuery appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have newly appended elements on my page that are being appended with Jquery.live(), I now want to change the value of those after those elements have been appended.

So something like

```
   $("#questionForm").empty();
        $.get("questionCreator.html", function(data){
            $("#questionForm").append(data);

        });
        var index=$(this).parent().index();
        id = index; 
        var associatedQuestion = idQuestionAssociation[index];
        var associatedResponses = idResponsesAssociation[index];
        if(associatedQuestion != null){
            $(".questionInput").val(associatedQuestion);
        }
```

So the .val() call, I think is not working because there is no .questionInput element initially, and this is appended. I feel like I should be using .live, or .delegate, or .on, but I'm not sure what event I should be using.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is asynchronous, which means that the elements you are trying to match with `$(".questionInput")` aren't in the DOM yet. You should put the rest of your DOM manipulation inside your callback.

```
    $.get("questionCreator.html", function(data){
        $("#questionForm").append(data);
        //change the values here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) to change the contents, but also calling `$(".questionInput")` could return an array so its best to loop over the possible elements - **unless it is unique then make it an id attribute (#questionInput)** to call it without the need for a loop.

```
$('.questionInput').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).replaceWith('I am replacing the content for .questionInput');
});
```

This should go inside the `get` function after it has returned the data.

Comment: ah sorry - the other guy got there faster - it worked though! thanks for the tip on id